# Find first date after today that matches a day-number and weekday

Tags: excel

Given any date, how do I find the **first** month and year in the future where the 31st of that month falls on a Wednesday, in other words, for today, 11 November 2020, I would like to see (31) March 2021. [Updated: Returned month should be March 2021]

Comment: So you never want to see ***February*** ??

Comment: No,there are other cases where I want to see the first 3/9/1217/20/25 on a Saturday, or 21/23 on a Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

@prino,

You could make use of Excel's [Iterative Calculation](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-iterative-calculation/), setting `Maximum Iterations` to `1000`.

In the example below, `A1` is the given date and `B1` receives the result (put the formula in `B1`):

```
=IF(B1=0,A1)+B1+IF(AND(WEEKDAY(B1,1)=4,DAY(B1)=31),0,1)
```

Comment: That works, well sort of, but for some days it iterates past the first date. Assuming A1 contains 2020-11-11, and I'm looking for the first Saturday 9th (of any month), I would expect to see 2021-01-09, but the formula returns 2021-10-09.

Comment: I deleted all formulae for the nine days required, re-entered them, and now the returned dates are correct, as verified by the calendar in the system tray.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 then

```
=LET(DayInMonth, DATE(YEAR($A$2),MONTH($A$2)+SEQUENCE(336,,0,1),$B$2),
     DOW,        WEEKDAY(DayInMonth),
     IsMatch,    (DAY(DayInMonth)=$B$2)*(DOW=$C$2)*(DayInMonth>=$A$2),
    XLOOKUP(1,IsMatch,DayInMonth,,0,1))
```

How it works:

1. Parameters are on the sheet (you could hard code these into the formula if you wish)
   `A2` is the start date (could be formula `=TODAY()`)
   `B2` is the day number in the month
   `C2` is the day of week code (1..7 = Sunday..Saturday)
2. The calander repeats every 28 years.  So only need to consider 12*28 = 336 months
3. DayInMonth is the specified date in each of the next 336 months, including this month.  Note: if a month does not have the specified day (eg 31 September does'nt exist)
4. DOW is the day of Week code for those dates
5. IsMatch is `1` if calculated DayInMonth matches specified DayInMonth (this excluded non-existant dates) AND Calculated DOW matches specified DOW AND calculated date is on or after start date
6. `XLOOKUP` returns the date of the first `1` in the IsMatch array

Comment: The calander repeats every 28 years. So only need to consider 12*28 = 336 months. Actually, it only repeats every 400 year, but I'm pretty sure that you need way less than 4800 months, and even way less than 336 to find all 7 weekdays on all 31 days. Just take the first of the month, in 2020 there's one on every (Mo..Su) day of the week.

Comment: Correct on the repeat period.  However,  the formula is still valid. Just change the 336 to whatever number you are comfortable with.